# What is the word for the set of words "million", "billion", "trillion"?

Tags: numbers

I am writing a program and I like to name things well.  I have to say if a value is in the thousands, millions, billions, or trillions.  My question is what do we call the set of number names that are ",000" from each other?

I know I am looking for something like "order of magnitude" but that is powers of ten.

Edit: I know about the "long scale" vs. "short scale" issue.  I am looking to see if there is a word that describes the set in English which as I understand it is always short scale.

Comment: So, um, how about *powers of thousand*, then. Or anything with [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales). Which is why naming variables is off-topic to begin with. Too many possibilities, and none are wrong.

Comment: How about "third order of magnitude"? Or just use [SI prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes).

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on whether you're using the short or long scale, a million and a billion can be separated by a different distance.

Comment: I think *long/short scale* relates to the fact that BrE *billion = million x million*, and *trillion = million x million*. Or at least *used to* - we all adopt the AmE convention *billion = **thousand** million*, and *trillion = thousand billion* today. They didn't get anywhere with this question [on cosmoquest.org](http://cosmoquest.org/forum/showthread.php?77765-A-thousand-million-billion) back in 2008.

Comment: You'll still hear long-scale terms like "thousand million" being passed around in the Commonwealth countries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Few in Britain have regarded a billion as a million million for at least 50 years.

Comment: Related question: What do you call the set of imaginary numbers that end in "-illion" (e.g., bazillion, gazillion, jillion, kazillion, squillion, and zillion)? And how would you order them? Wikipedia has a discussion of them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers

Comment: This is just a follow on to the Orders of Magnitude answer - there's a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)
(Just for future reference)

Answer (score 2):

The general term is "orders of magnitude". These words define a certain multiple of a quantity and thus the overall size of the "scale" on which we are measuring, unlike a "unit of measure" which defines what a quantity of "one" is on the scale.